# iOS: Change draft buttons tint color in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to change the tint color of the "Save Draft" \ "Delete Draft" \ "Cancel" buttons in MFMailComposeViewController?

I changed the tint color of the top buttons ("Cancel" \ "Send"), but I also want to change the color of the "draft" buttons.

I can't find it on the documentation..

Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply set the mail composer view controller's view's tint color and it will be used for the bar button items as well as the non-destructive alert controller buttons. Tested on iOS 10.

```
let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
...
mail.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Important the mail composition interface itself is not customisable and must not be modified by your application.

Read the [Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html)